# MySQL's "SOURCE" returns Error 2 despite the Path is correct

Tags: mysql

I was trying to import a SQL Script into my DB but I get the Error 2.

That's the Command I tried in MySQL and the Error I get:
[image]

Now, here's the path of the file "script.sql":

[image]

So I can't understand what's wrong, this should work.. Anyone can help?

Comment: check permission. mysql might run as another user, who does not have access to your user folder.

Comment: @ProGu there is only one user on this PC

Comment: well, windows have accounts for running services, for example `LOCAL SERVICE` account. not users you used to logon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the path issue. so put script.sql file into another drive.

D:\\data/script.sql OR D://data/script.sql

USE database name;
SOURCE D:\data/script.sql;