# mysqldump Wordpress issue

Tags: mysql, wordpress

While doing mysqldump command for databases about 2GB I get an error in Wordpress sites "error establishing database connection". It's about 10-15 sec while mysqldump is running.

Can someone help me where should I digging?

max_user_connections = 50
max_connections = 800

Server 48 cores, 128 GB RAM

Thanks in advance.

Comment: And if none of those solutions do the trick, [try googling](https://www.google.com/search?q=mysqldump+lost+connection&rlz=1C1GCEB_enUS884US884&oq=mysqldump+lost+connection)

Comment: Follow this steps;
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69808249/mysqls-source-returns-error-2-despite-the-path-is-correct/69808571#69808571

Answer (score 0):

If your on innoDB consider using:

--single-transaction=TRUE check the [man page here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_single-transaction)

--extended-insert is quicker when updating a DB from a dump file and makes the dump file smaller.

--quick makes the creation of the dump quicker.

When backing up from WorldPress --add-drop-table parameter must be also specified. More info [here](https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/backing-up-your-database/#using-straight-mysql-mariadb-commands).